# Grails Spring Security plugin - "Cannot invoke isLoggedIn() on null object" error in grails-2.3.0.RC1

Tags: java, spring, grails, grails-2.0

I have spent a lot of time searching for help on this issue but none. I am constantly getting this error after i install spring security plugin in my grails-2.3.0.RC1 app.

Here's the the code i used. I have not modified the generated templates except create a controller and add @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN']) to it.

The login controller

```
import grails.converters.JSON

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
class LoginController {

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the authenticationTrustResolver.
     */
    def authenticationTrustResolver

    /**
     * Dependency injection for the springSecurityService.
     */
    def springSecurityService

    /**
     * Default action; redirects to 'defaultTargetUrl' if logged in, /login/auth otherwise.
     */
    def index = {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }
        else {
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the login page.
     */
    def auth = {

        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        String view = 'auth'
        String postUrl = "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"
        render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                                   rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]
    }

    /**
     * The redirect action for Ajax requests.
     */
    def authAjax = {
        response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
        response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
    }

    /**
     * Show denied page.
     */
    def denied = {
        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() &&
                authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(SCH.context?.authentication)) {
            // have cookie but the page is guarded with IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY
            redirect action: 'full', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * Login page for users with a remember-me cookie but accessing a IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY page.
     */
    def full = {
        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        render view: 'auth', params: params,
            model: [hasCookie: authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(SCH.context?.authentication),
                    postUrl: "${request.contextPath}${config.apf.filterProcessesUrl}"]
    }

    /**
     * Callback after a failed login. Redirects to the auth page with a warning message.
     */
    def authfail = {

        def username = session[UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY]
        String msg = ''
        def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]
        if (exception) {
            if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.expired")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.disabled")
            }
            else if (exception instanceof LockedException) {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.locked")
            }
            else {
                msg = g.message(code: "springSecurity.errors.login.fail")
            }
        }

        if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
            render([error: msg] as JSON)
        }
        else {
            flash.message = msg
            redirect action: 'auth', params: params
        }
    }

    /**
     * The Ajax success redirect url.
     */
    def ajaxSuccess = {
        render([success: true, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name] as JSON)
    }

    /**
     * The Ajax denied redirect url.
     */
    def ajaxDenied = {
        render([error: 'access denied'] as JSON)
    }
}
```

Here's the bootstrap file:

```
import com.security.*

   class BootStrap {

       def init = { servletContext ->
        def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true) 
        def userRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

        def testUser = new User(username:'emman', enabled: true, password: 'password') 
        testUser.save(flush: true)
        UserRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

       }
       def destroy = {
       }
   }
```

And the secured controller:

```
package springsecurity

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured


@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
class HomeController {

    def index() {

    }
}
```

And heres the error message when i try to access the controller:

```
NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /springsecurity/login/auth;jsessionid=CABE1DB8CD4C6689CD137F51DBEE85CD
Cannot invoke method isLoggedIn() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method isLoggedIn() on null object
        at LoginController$_closure2.doCall(LoginController.groovy:46)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Am able to attach the testapp but don't know how to do that here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, this problem is related to an issue with grails-2.3.0.RC1 not injecting service bean for plugins correctly.

I was able to fix my problem by adding this to grails-app/conf/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    springConfig.addAlias "springSecurityService", "springSecurityCoreSpringSecurityService"
}
```

This makes grails to inject the service first before anything.
If you have similar problems using grails-2.3.0RC1, you can add an alias to the resources.groovy file to fix this error. For example:

```
beans={
   springConfig.addAlias "serviceName","pluginNameServiceName"
}
```

You can see the jira that was opened for this problem here http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10301

Hope this helps anyone with similar issues.

Comment: Please try this again next week when we release RC2 - hacks like this won't be needed.

Comment: Okay. Would be nice not to have to do this because i had to do the same for grails async mail plugin too.

Comment: Yep. I wish I had a pet monkey.

Comment: Works just fine without the hack for RC2. Thank you.